# Difference between remotes/origin and origin

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working on a new repository on GitLab, however when I list the branches it shows: `remotes/origin/branch1`.
The times I worked with git it would show only: `origin/branch1`.
If I create a branch like: `git checkout -b myBranch` would it show like: `remotes/origin/myBranch` or do I have to make some kind of config before.
Sorry if it's a stupid question, I am new in this.

Comment: If you create a new branch locally `git checkout -b myBranch` it will just be `myBranch`. It will not be remote on origin, unless you push it. Then there might be both `myBranch` and `origin/myBranch`. They are different things.

Comment: what command did you write for listing the branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This guy is Harcourt Fenton Mudd.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Harcourt_Fenton_Mudd)  Is he also Harry Mudd?

(Hint: Yes.  Yes he is.  Well, modulo whether you're into Star Trek, anyway.  Okay, that wasn't a *hint*.)

> `origin/branch1` [vs] `remotes/origin/branch1`

Both of these are actually abbreviations: the full spelling of this name is `refs/remotes/origin/branch1`.  Git lops off the `refs/remotes/` part, except when—for no apparent reason<sup>1</sup>—it only lops off the `refs/` part.

The full name begins with `refs/`.  According to [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), that makes it a [*ref*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefrefaref) or *reference*.  This is a generalization of branch names, tag names, and other such names, so that one piece of code inside Git—the reference handling code—can deal with all the different kinds of refs.  It also means that if someone hands you a full reference, you can tell what kind it is:

- `refs/heads/name` is the branch name *`name`*;
- `refs/tags/name` is the tag name *`name`*; and
- `refs/remotes/remote/name` is a two-part *remote-tracking name*.<sup>2</sup>

Confusingly, these two part names are made up of:

- a *remote name*, which is not a *remote-tracking name*; plus
- your Git's copy of some other Git's branch name, as of the last time that your Git saw their Git's branch name (and corresponding commit hash ID).

The *remote* in this case is `origin`.  A remote is a short name under which your Git can store some facts.  The primary fact stored under a remote is a URL: your Git will use this URL to contact the *other* Git, when you run `git fetch` or `git push`.<sup>3</sup>

What this all boils down to is that when you see `refs/remotes/origin/branch1`, that tells you that:

- your Git has, or had, a *remote* named `origin`;
- at some point, your Git called up some other Git *using* that name;
- at that point, *their* Git had a *branch* name, `refs/heads/branch1`, or `branch1` for short; and
- your Git copied that branch name into your own repository, renaming it to `origin/branch1` (for short) to keep it away from *your* **branch** names.  Your branch names are *yours*.  They are not to be messed with just because some other Git has some branch names!  The other guy using that other Git can mess with his branch names all he wants; your Git won't mess with yours just because he messed with his.

If you want to create your own branch name `branch1` (full name `refs/heads/branch1`), you're free to do that.  If you'd like it to associate, in some way, with *their* `branch1` (your `origin/branch1`), you can do that too, by setting your `origin/branch1` as the *upstream* of your `branch1`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The command-line command that is squirrelly here is `git branch`: `git branch` lists (local) *branch names* and lops off `refs/heads/` from each, and `git branch -r` lists *remote-tracking names* and lops off `refs/remotes/` from each; but `git branch -a` lists both, lopping off `refs/heads/` from the branch names while lopping off only `refs/` from the remote-tracking names.  I have never seen anything that says *why* it does this.  There are probably [hysterical raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html) involved.

<sup>2</sup>Git documentation calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but they don't act like *branch* names, and I find the word *branch* in this phrase just muddies the waters.  Calling them *remote-tracking names* is not *much* of an improvement, but it seems better.

<sup>3</sup>You can store more than one URL, if for some reason you want to `git fetch` from one URL and `git push` to a different one.  You can also store some configuration items under the remote name.  The command that manipulates remote names and their stored URLs and other data is `git remote`.

---

#### Summary

You've learned these technical terms:

- *remote:* a short name for a URL.  There are relatively few restrictions on these names, and they don't have a long spelling and a short one.
- *branch name:* a name (that keeps track of a commit ID—we didn't go into this much detail) that your own Git maintains for you, once you have your Git create it.  A branch name has a fully spelled out long form, which you can use when it's in trouble,<sup>4</sup> the way "Harry Mudd" becomes "Harcourt Fenton Mudd" when [Stella Mudd](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stella_Mudd) is angry with him.
- *remote-tracking name:* a name (that keeps track of a commit ID) that your Git copies, rather slavishly, from some other Git, but changes it around during the copying, so that it won't ever conflict with any of your *branch* names.
- *upstream:* a way to link a branch name to some other name—usually a remote-tracking name, but you can use a branch name here too—to make some things more convenient.  (We haven't gone into detail about what this makes convenient.)

---

<sup>4</sup>You might wonder when a branch name could possibly be in trouble.  The answer is: when it's also a tag name, or some other name.  What if you accidentally make `v1` as both a tag *and* a branch?  There are some rules that Git uses, but they're pretty weird: the tag name often wins, but not always, and it gets confusing.  But you can just write out the full name—`refs/heads/v1` or `refs/tags/v1`—to get around that, or use an abbreviated name, but one *less* abbreviated: `heads/v1` or `tags/v1`.

(The `git describe` command sometimes prints out `heads/name`, to warn you that it's a branch name instead of a tag name.)

Answer (score 2):

**@torek** has explained deeply on this. Credits to him.

If you write a command `git checkout -b mybranch` then it will create a new branch named `mybranch` in your `local` and it will switch to that new branch from the default branch so that you can work on that branch. Tip: *The default branch is master or main branch depending upon version control application you are working on*.

Now if you do `git branch`. It will show your local branches that comes from `ref/heads` reference like `master` and `*mybranch`. * indicates that your `Head` is pointed to that branch.

```
$ git branch
  *mybranch
  master
```

If you do `git branch -r`. It will show remote branches from `ref/remotes`.

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/master
```

For displaying the list of both local and remote branches which comes from `ref/heads` and `ref/` reference, you need to use `git branch -a`.

```
$ git branch -a
  *mybranch
  master
  remote/origin/master
```

If you want to push the newly created branch into the remote repo.

```
git push origin mybranch
```

If you working alone then you need to first check out to master branch then merge it with the newly created branch to the `master` branch by

```
git checkout master
git merge mybranch
```

If you are working in a team then you need to do the `pull request` so that everyone in your team knows that you have pushed your new branch and requires the approval of the team member to merge the branch to the master branch.